# How to remove code syntax from message (discord.py)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a command to run python code inputted by the user, and have the bot send the output back to the user. My issue is being able to put the code in a file and remove the code block syntax (discord uses the same syntax as stack overflow for code blocks). I have googled the issue and tried a couple ways of doing this.

Here is what I am doing now:

````
@bot.command
async def python(ctx, *, code): #code is what the user inputs
    with open('python.py', 'w') as f:
        for line in code:
            if '```python' in line:
                line = re.sub(```python, '', line) # sometimes "python" wont be there so i do a check for it

            line = re.sub('```', '', line)
            f.write(line)

    # the rest of the code is just running it, and sending the output, which isn't the issue
````

Comment: I am making a command that grabs the code in the block inputted by a user, run it, and the bot will send the output in the chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the re module

````py
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> content = """
... ```py
... import random
... print(random.randint(1, 10))
... ```"""
>>> 
>>> code = re.sub("```python|```py|```", "", content)
>>> print(code)

import random
print(random.randint(1, 10))
````

It's kind of hard to see it here, but it works fine

Comment: Works perfectly! For some reason when I do "```python" it sees py before it sees python. Added a check for if "thon" is left and it works perfectly now haha. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah makes sense, you can change the order to `"```python|```py|```"` and it should work, sorry for that! Also remember to accept the answer if it helped :)